# Slack Bolt Python: how to make the input field in modal optional?

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

I'm using modal to collect data. I opened a view by the following code:

```
view = {
    "type": "modal",
    "title": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "My App",
        "emoji": True
    },
    "submit": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Submit",
        "emoji": True
    },
    "close": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Cancel",
        "emoji": True
    },
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "input",
            "element": {
                "type": "plain_text_input",
                "action_id": "plain_text_input-action"
            },
            "label": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Please leave feedback here",
                "emoji": True
            }
        }
    ]
    }
slack_client.views_open(trigger_id=body['trigger_id'],view=view)
```

[image]

I want to make the input text optional, that is, even though the user leaves the input field blank, he/she can still submit the modal. Can this be realized?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add `"optional": true` as property of input block.

```
"blocks": [
        {
            "type": "input",

            "optional": true,

            "element": {
                "type": "plain_text_input",
                "action_id": "plain_text_input-action"
            },
            "label": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Label",
                "emoji": true
            }
        }
    ]
```